# Developing an IOS Game in unity on windows

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am about to start working on a project and was wondering, if I develop my game in unity on windows, will I be able to make a finished product there, then just transfer it over to a mac to publish to the app store? Or do I actually need a mac to make the game?

Comment: AFAIK, you need a Mac (or a Hackintosh) to build it for the App Store.

Comment: Unity Cloud Build may work, or there are various other Mac in the cloud based services you can use to build/sign/upload from.

Answer (score 3):

You can make the game on Windows. But you will need a mac to build it for ios. When you build for ios from Unity it creates an xcode project. You need to open that xcode project in the xcode IDE on a mac and then build it again in xcode onto your iphone, or onto the apple app store.
You will need a relatively new mac with the catalina OS or later on it. Older macs can't be upgraded to the newer OS, and you need the new OS to be allowed to install the latest xcode, which is the only one that is allowed build ios apps.
Also macincloud wont work for this purpose, it does not support building to ios.

Just fyi, I do all my work on Windows and only use the mac for building to ios.